# One-Page "Gated" Facebook Tab/App with Permissions

Tags: php, facebook, permissions, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a very difficult time with a Facebook Tab/App that I'm trying to create with very specific needs:

1. It must be contained within one file -- index.php (auxiliary files like .js, .css, and other .php files as includes are fine).
2. It must have a splash page that calls for permissions upon "opting" in (ie: clicking a "go" button)
3. It must be done in the PHP SDK

Now, I've used the Javascript SDK for this before and its' quite easy. I'm attempting to do this in PHP and its throwing some wrenches in my system.

This is my basic setup:

In the index.php, I include a global.php in the top of the file which handles the whole facebook SDK include and:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
));
```

I then "gate" what is being loaded based on a signed request (`$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();` `signed_request['app_data']`) . If the signed request "app_data" is set to "flash_load", permissions are checked. If permissions pass, a flash file is loaded otherwise permissions are requested. If app_data != 'flash_load' the splash page is loaded.

General page flow:

```
Page load

    If( app_data == flash_load )

        check permissions

        if permissions

            render flash

        else 

            request permissions

    else

        render splash page
```

The splash page has a button that says "Go" which links DIRECTLY to the Page Tab (ie: http://www.facebook.com/{{{PAGE_NAME}}}?v=app_{{{APP_ID}}}&app_data=flash_load). I also have this same URL set as the Website with Facebook Login SITE URL @ https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{{{APP_ID}}}

All this is working fine and well with the explicit exception of this flow:

If a user doesn't have permissions:

1. they visit the tab
2. They are prompted by the splash screen
3. They click "Go" which re-directs to http://www.facebook.com/{{{PAGE_NAME}}}?v=app_{{{APP_ID}}}&app_data=flash_load
4. The page (index.php) reloads with a signed request app_data = flash_load
5. Permissions are granted
6. index.php reloads to the SPLASH page.

How do I make it so that for the **INITIAL** reload **AFTER** granting permissions the flash file is loaded and not the splash?

I have tried adding `state` to the `redirect_uri` but have been unable to grab the value using `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, or `$facebook->getSignedRequest();`

I've also tried to use `$_SERVER` to grab the URL and parse that out, but that doesn't refer to the Facebook URL.

Side-note: Every subsequent loads after the first reload after granting permissions should load the splash as normal.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask for the permissions, so you may use the presence of `user_id` or `oauth_token` to ascertain that the user has already authorized your app and you may load the flash file instead of the splash screen.

The documentation about the fields of [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) describes the same as

> Some fields and values, the user_id and oauth_token for example will only be passed if the user has [logged into](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) your app.